Best saw to cut through aluminum siding and drywall to install a dog door?
So my wife and I just moved into a new cape cod house in New England, and I need to put in a dog door. We're gonna put it in the mud room which has vinyl sheeting on the inside, drywall (?) in the middle and aluminum sheeting on the outside. I have a circular saw and a reciprocating saw, but the local hardware store has a sale on and it's a great excuse to get a new tool. I was considering getting a jigsaw or an oscillating tool, any thoughts? We've got a few other projects coming up, so l'd like to get the best for this one specifically, but any suggestions would be appreciated.

"best" is subjective, depending on what you have in hand, your budget, your skills and your patience.

A jig saw is basically a smaller version of the reciprocating saw. so it's probably not adding much to your toolset.
A fine tooth blade on the reciprocating saw is probably sufficient, but the oscillating tool might do a slightly better job.
Realisitcally one of the hacksaw blade grips and a fine tooth hacksaw blade is all you really need is all you really need, but you have the reciprocating saw so use that.

If you need permission to get a new tool, permission granted.
But you'll probably want an angle grinder with a metal cut blade  to do the aluminum siding. A circular saw with the blade reversed will cut the vinyl without doing a tearout, or with some skill, you can use the reciprocating saw and  fine-toothed blade to do the same. An oscilating multi-tool will also work and be safer.

Can get a metal-cutting blade for an oscillating multi-tool. :)
